# Load JS File according to current Controller using GruntFile in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

Hi I am new with sails and gruntfile. Would like to know if is possible to load javascript file/s according to the current controller used?

For example, I have this directory:

```
> api/controllers/
>>  HomeController.js
>>  Module1Controller.js
>>  Module2Controller.js
>
> assets/linker/js/VM/
>>  home.js
>>  module1.js
>>  module2.js
```

I want to load the following:

If the page is currently at Home Page: I will load only

> <script src="/assets/linker/js/VM/home.js">

and so on...

If its possible? How to do it using **gruntfile**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a use case for Grunt.  What you want is what @gorelative alluded to above; a piece of code in your EJS file that outputs the controller name.  Using Sails v0.10.x, you could do:

```
<script src="/assets/js/VM/<%= req.options.controller %>.js"></script>
```

On Sails v0.9.x, it would be:

```
<script src="/assets/js/VM/<%= req.target.controller %>.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have done similar solution with this, but using express.js where I'm using the req.target.controller to get the controllerName and fetch all needed js files. coz some of the pages needs to load other js files which is not based on the controller name, so really case to case. Once I got the js filenames, I passed it to res.locals.loadJS and from layout I parse it to include each js files... So far its working fine with us, but still trying to find other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

i don't believe this is possible as grunt is only ran when you lift the server initially.. you might be better off using conditional ejs blocks in your views.

Comment: oh oks. I though its possible with grunt... :(